# AppFabricCaching Service DOWN

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, distributedcache, app-fabric

I'm trying to troubleshoot why App Fabric Caching Service is DOWN on SharePoint 2013. I'm new to the installation so unsure of history.

The  following line gives an ONLINE status

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq "SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"} | select Server, Status
```

Then tried

```
Use-CacheCluster
Get-CacheHost
```

and get :

> xx.domain.x.x.x  AppFabricCachingService  DOWN

Windows Services show AppFabric Caching Service as not Running and set on Automatic. Tried manually starting but stops, is this normal behaviour?

Thanks

UPDATE on actions performed:

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> $instanceName =”SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService” 
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername}

If($serviceInstance -ne $null){ $serviceInstance.Delete()}

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq "SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"} | select Server, Status


PS C:\Windows\system32> Use-CacheCluster
Get-CacheHost

HostName : CachePort                          Service Name            Service Status Version Info
--------------------                          ------------            -------------- ------------
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.uk:22233 AppFabricCachingService DOWN           3 [3,3][1,3]


PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

[image]

ERROR In Events log
Faulting application name: DistributedCacheService.exe, version: 1.0.4632.0, time stamp: 0x4eafeccf
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18340, time stamp: 0x57366075
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000008a5c
Faulting process id: 0x1b44
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2da401b0fad47
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files\AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\DistributedCacheService.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 5c8b5bac-4633-11e7-8160-005056850f1f
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not normal, you have to fix the your cluster.

1st run this script to cleare all the running instances of the DC

```
$instanceName =”SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService” 
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername}

If($seriveInstance -ne $null){ $serviceInstance.Delete()}
```

Now run this command and it should not show any thing

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq "SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"} | select Server, Status
```

Finally Run the

```
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

Wait for minutes now check the status again.

```
Use-CacheCluster
Get-CacheHost
```

Comment: Tried above and when execute 'Get-SPServiceInstance.....' the status is DISABLED and 'Get-CacheHost' shows as DOWN

Comment: after running the deleted script(1st), what is the stauts

Comment: After delete script, the second script displays nothing, but the 4th script shows DOWN

Comment: did you run the add-spdistributedcacheservice....?

Comment: I executed your suggestion in order, so after the deletion I checked with the second script and nothing was being reported, then ran add-spdistributedcacheservice.... and finally the 4th script.

Comment: what is appfabric service status from the Service console on the server?

Comment: In Services, AppFabric not started and set to Automatic, I've updated question with screenshot

Comment: Can it be related to memory allocation of the Distributed Cache service?

Comment: run the 1st script, then check the status...after that go to Service console and make sure the APP fabric is not started and change it settings to disabled...Now run the add-spditributed...script...wait and check the Appfabric starus from console

Comment: Ok, will try now. BTW in CA the Distributed Cache is stopped in case it makes any difference.

Comment: Ran the 1st script, AppFabric in Services remained not started, changed Startup Type to Disabled, ran add-spditributed...script and waited, however AppFabric in Services is still Disabled

Comment: Is add command completed successfully? Check event log ( application and system logs)

Comment: Cannot see any specific errors, however found Distributed Cache error and updated Question.. This maybe the issue?

Comment: This error was seen a few hours ago and doesn't appear to be reoccurring, probably due to the commands above. Will check in the morning.

Comment: The Instance now states ONLINE but the last script states DOWN.
Also, on the wfe I cannot find  WindowsFabricAdministrators group ?
Should I run the AppFabric Wizard?

Comment: You can run it, it will not hurt rather fix the missing stuff

Comment: I experienced exact same error. I ran the same script and get exact same out come. It seems the status still "Down". May I know how it was resolved at the end?

Answer (score -1):

The Distributed Cache service **is not running from Services**, so to start the Distributed Cache service you should use SharePoint 2013 Management Shell
as following command:

```
$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService" 
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername} 
$serviceInstance.Provision()
```

Then run the below cmdlet and check the status

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq "SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"} | select Server, Status
```

If the status still down. try to follow the steps mentioned by @Waqas.

Also, check [Manage the Distributed Cache service in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Did not work for me, since the instance returned by `Get-SPServiceInstance` was null.