# Cachehostinfo is null - Error in WFE01 while configuring Distributed Cache in my multi server Prod.Farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, distributedcache, wfe

Am trying t configure the DC-distributed cache for a WFE for my SP 2013 SP1 WITH APRIL 2017 CU - MULTISERVER farm 
but when i run the powershell cmdlets for creating the DC -Distributed Cache

`Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance`

it thrown error:

> cachehostinf is null

Update:
now  am getting

> failed to connect to hosts in the cluster

[image: cacheinfohostisnull]

Comment: See: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55076/sharepoint-2013-distributed-cache-cachehostinfo-null

Comment: did you ran this Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance?

Comment: yes, already  ran those.  the strange thing is that, its perfectly working on my WFE02 and failed in WFE01 server! am following this link : http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2015/09/17/how-to-patch-sharepoint-distributed-cache-the-proper-way/   Ran those powershell cmds fro the WFE02 , and worked fine. then  i went to WFE01 and run the same , it failed!!

Comment: Your updated error log *again* leads to tens of results by using e.g. Google. Have you tried those solutions available effortlessly?

Comment: ok,thnx! :-) Am trying with those results from google ... of course ..am looking into it. will update here as soon as i get resolution. one update is that i went to services.msc and STOPPED the appfabric service and trying to provision the DC serv instance again .

Comment: AppFabrice Service is running, check from services console on server? also check this reply https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/216964/21563

Comment: my issue( i think ) is Web01 IS UNABLE TO see the status of WEB02. When i go to Web02 and run the commands, its giving me the status as UP.but the same is NOT happening when i run these cmds from WEB01.

Comment: ie, when i  try to the get-cachehost , its showing as UP and UNKNOWN in my web01 server and when i run the same in web02 server, both status are UP .

Comment: follow the 4 steps, i mentioned in the that reply. After step 2, go to service console and make sure App fabric service is stopped. if not stop it and change it to disabled. then run the add command and wait for couple of minutes

Comment: hi @WaqasSarwarMVP, based on your link, your answer on that link, using the powershell script, i was able to fix the issue. Please put it in the answer box, i can mark this as an answer

Comment: Glad, I was able to solve ur problem. I added it as answer.

Comment: One more request, I have seen u have too many open question, it is really helpful for the community...if you mark  the answer if any reply helpful or add step which help u to solve the issue. This will in great interest of community. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st run this script to cleare all the running instances of the DC

```
$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"  
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.server.name) -eq $env:computername} 

If($serviceInstance -ne $null){ $serviceInstance.Delete()}
```

Now run this command and it should not show any thing

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.service.tostring()) -eq "SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"} | select Server, Status
```

Now make sure that appfabric service is stoped and start type disabled. Check it from services console.

Finally Run the

```
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

Wait for minutes now check the status again.

```
Use-CacheCluster 
Get-CacheHost
```